# How can I export my Oracle database as a file?

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, file-extension

I am dealing with a Java web project for my course. I have been told to add my database file too while sending my homework. However, I have no idea about database file since I am using a database in a project for the first time. I am using Oracle 11g database for storing and manipulating necessary data.

I have written several JSP scripts. I access to the Oracle database while running these files with the line

```
connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","selubamih","123456");
```

But I am not sure how can I send this database to my teacher because I am using it through the connection with my password. How can I export the database to send it as a file along with my JSP codes? I searched files for keeping databases, it seems like `.csv` and `.db` are most commonly used extensions. Should I export my database as one of these files? If so, how can I export my database? I will appreciate any of your help.

Comment: You should ask your teacher. Did you choose Oracle because your teacher told you to?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It is not easy for us to contact teacher. I did choose Oracle database, she hasn't told anything about the database.

Comment: expdp command is used to export a database in oracle.  Read up on that.

Comment: I finally solved it using the command `exp user/password FILE=data.dmp`